# Cannot access Open VPN Management Console via Port Forwarding

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, openvpn

I just set up OpenVPN on my Raspberry running headless Raspbian with the server config file provided by my VPN Provider "IP Vanish" and appended the following line in the config file:

```
management 127.0.0.1 6001 stdin
```

Afterwards I started the service like this:

```
sudo openvpn --config PATH/ipvanish-XXX.ovpn
```

IP Checks yielded that the connection is established as desired.

I want to access the management portal from my Macbook on the same network using port forwarding:

```
ssh -i XXX.pem -L 3000:localhost:6001 pi@192.168.1.9
```

The login works fine, but when I go to 127.0.0.1:3000 Safari says

> Cancelled load because it is using HTTP/0.9

and Chrome just says that it send an invalid response.

My google research on the "HTTP/0.9" issue didn't really get me anywhere. Is the protocol used for the management portal just too old or what's the real issue here?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, I missed that the management interface for openvpn is a COMMAND LINE interface.

A connection with e.g.

```
nc 127.0.0.1 6001
```

works just fine.

This answer just in case someone else is under the false assumption, it's a web interface.